# How to get value for a range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'd have thought I could find how to do this easily but it hasn't been so.

I thought would be something like:

```
= CONCAT(B32:B40)
```

Answer (score 1):

With more googling, I found that Excel has the function TEXTJOIN() and so does Google Sheets